# ScriptDb, how to tell a object has a key or not

Tags: database, google-apps-script

I have such objects in ScriptDb,
[{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:0,b:0}]
How do I query object without key c?
It seems the only way is to query all object using db.query({}), then use something like "typeof result.c == 'undefined'".
Is there a way to do it in ScriptDb? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that to get records without c:

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var result = db.query({c: db.not(db.anyValue())});
while (result.hasNext()) {
  var current = result.next();
  Logger.log ("a= "+current.a+", c="+current.c);
}
```

The ones with c:

```
var result = db.query({c: db.anyValue()});
```

These functions (not, anyValue...) are documented in [Class ScriptDbInstance](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptdbinstance)